# How can I borderline an empty cell?

Tags: excel, border

I have some cells with IF statements and when it returns False, it will print "". 
When I try to put a borderline on these cells, they don't show. I'm assuming it is because these cells are empty.

Any ideas on how I can get the borderlines to show? My temporary solution is to write "." and then make the "." white so that it doesn't show. But I would have to do this for many cells and am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells containing the empty string `""` are different then blank cells. You can get a border around each one using conditional formatting on the desired range with the following formula rule (and setting your formatting to have outside borders):

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),LEN(A1)=0)
```

In place of A1, use whatever the top left cell in your range is.

Comment: You were definitely right about conditional formatting. I didn't fully understand the formula you gave me so I tried clearing the existing rules and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: The formula says if the cell is not blank and its value has zero length, then it should be formatted.